# Where to find/buy full list of updated ISP IP ranges?

Tags: ip, isp

I need to assign IPs of a huge daily visitor IPs to the ISP they come from. So I thought of buying the list of IP addresses corresponding to ISPs.

Now so far I have only found:

[ip2country](http://www.ip2country.net/ip2country/IP-COUNTRY-ISP.html)

But I am not sure how legit they are and dont want to get a database full of wrong data!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the primary providers of IP information is MaxMind.

http://www.maxmind.com/

While they have many products, this one is their ISP database:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/isp

They have a number of interface methods as well (e.g. c library, apache module, php modules).

The sites I've worked with have mainly used it for GeoIP purposes tied into web analytics.

Comment: Is there anyone that sells the data with Email addresses?

Answer (score 2):

IP to country conversion is not too difficult, and that list is probably as accurate as any.

However, beware anyone that tells you that they can manage more accuracy than country as location since this is something that my company has been looking into seriously for a while. In the UK, many, if not most, people will appear to be in London because that is where the assigned IP is listed to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this data from my own service, https://ipinfo.io. The primary IPinfo.io service is the API:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8?token=$TOKEN
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0840",
  "postal": "94035",
  "phone": "650",
  "asn": {
    "asn": "AS15169",
    "name": "Google LLC",
    "domain": "google.com",
    "route": "8.8.8.0/24",
    "type": "hosting"
  },
  "company": {
    "name": "Google LLC",
    "domain": "google.com",
    "type": "hosting"
  }
}
```

But all of the data returned in the API, plus some additional data, is available for download.